# нужно задетектить запуск приложения с помощью flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, dart-ui

нужно задетектить запуск приложения с помощью flutter

например я запустил youtube ,flutter приложение должно задетектить либо не дать запустится приложению и должно появится специальное окно что нельзя запустить или просто появится окно (что вы можете реализовать то и отвечайте)

если будет работать и на android и на ios было бы здорово